# Remainders questions help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we divide a number by 3, 4 ,5 , 6 , we have  the remainders 2, 3 , 4 , 5. Is there any way to  get a pattern without guessing so many numbers and checking by 3, 4 ,5 ,6?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is first Modular Arithmetic problem I'm solving, I hope it's correct.
We have
$$-1\equiv3 \mod( y )$$
$$-1\equiv4\mod (y)$$
$$-1\equiv5\mod (y)$$
$$-1\equiv6\mod (y)$$

then
$$-1\equiv60\mod(y)$$

Any Number of the form $60p-1$, ( $p \in \mathbb N$) will have mentioned properties.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We are told that our number $x$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $3$, $4$, $5$, and $6$.

Comment: The answer is given 60. But i want a easy way to get that.

Comment: How did you solve?

Comment: The smallest positive integer is $59$. The solutions are all $x$ congruent to $-1$ (or equivalently $59$) modulo $60$. Note that $60$ is the least common multiple of $3,4,5,6$.

Comment: If 60 is the answer we have not get any reminders. I am a bit confused@!

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yes, I figured that. Thanks. :)

Comment: As I wrote earlier, $60$ is not the answer. One answer is $59$. All answers are given by $59+60a$, or equivalently $-1+60b$, where $a,b$ range over the integers.

Comment: I was asking for his solution. Reading 60 confused me as ofcourse, 60 won't satisfy the given conditions.

Comment: @ComplexGuy: You have the 4 equations as stated by André Nicolas. Solve the first to get $x$ in some general form ($x=3k-1$). Plug the general form in the second equation and get $k$ in general form and then plug it back to get a new expression for $x$. Do this for equation 3 and 4 and you'll have your answer.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi: Your suggestion is good for a more general problem. In this particular problem, one can take advantage of the fact that all the congruences have shape $x\equiv m-1\pmod{m}$, or equivalently $x\equiv -1\pmod{m}$.

Comment: Understood, Sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can also build up a solution quite easily.

$N\equiv -1$ mod $3$ means $N=3a-1$, and $N\equiv 1$ mod $4$ means $N=4b-1$

So $3a-1=4b-1$ or $3a=4b$ so that $b=3c, a=4c$ and $N=12c-1$

This is where things could go wrong, because this is not guaranteed to be compatible with the remainder on division by $6$ - fortunately it is.

Then $N=5d-1=12c-1$ gives $c=5e, d=12e, N=60e-1$